# Fix nav to top only on desktop

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to fix the nav to the top of the screen but only on screen `widths > 782px`

So far I've got half the script running fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ah4ta7xc/1/

However my method leaves an unwanted gap at the top when the class `sticky-menu` is applied.

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">Logo and stuff</div>
<div id="main-menu">Site menu</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 3000px;
}

#foo {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#main-menu {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 30; 
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.sticky-menu {
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 782) {
        $('#main-menu').addClass('sticky-menu');
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 782) {
            $('#main-menu').addClass('sticky-menu');
        }
    else {
        $('#main-menu').removeClass('sticky-menu');
    }
    });  
});
```

Comment: I think I don't get what you are trying to achieve, if you want the same layout as posted then you need to move the #main-menu div to the top (ie: top:0;) but also take care of the #foo div when the page first displays. Is that true? Also I recommend you using media queries.

Comment: Consider using media queries. They exist explicitly to cater to cases where you want a web page to look different for different devices. E.g. desktop, small screens (i.e. smartphones), and even printers if you are printing.

Answer (score 0):

You could add these lines to the CSS for the body:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to only apply the sticky nav when the scroll reaches that point with something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
     var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
     var topDist = $('#main-menu').offset().top;

     if (scroll > topDist) {
         $('#main-menu').addClass('sticky-menu');
     } else {
         $('#main-menu').removeClass('sticky-menu');
     }
});
```